# Why are human bones usually curved?

Tags: human-anatomy

Is there any simple explanation as to why human bones are more curved than straight and are thicker at ends and thinner in the middle?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by curved? Do you mean the surfaces of the bone are curved because of the greater width of the ends, or do you think the actual bone (i.e. the actual axis of the bone) is curved (one is true, the other may be an illusion, or present in disease.)

Comment: @anongoodnurse - I meant the axis.

Comment: Thanks. The anatomical axis of normal long bones is usually a straight line, but the outsides can be curved. Just clearing up terminology. Ribs are obviously curved, and quite commonly fractured as a result.  This might be rightly deleted as an answer in a comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The slight curve allows bone to absorb shocks better.

This curve allows the bone to act like a spring and flex a little bit. One issue as bone get older is that they become harder and, therefore, more brittle which leads to the elderly breaking bones for a fall that younger individuals just get a bruise. Young children often get stick or "splitting" breaks where the bone does not break but separates as the bone is still soft.

The ends tend to be thicker as that is where the joints are and there are forces that need to be absorbed.

Of course, if the load applied to the bone is just too much or it is a sharp shock then bones will break, but really the skeleton is nature's design for a suspension system to allow us to do what we need to do walk, run, stand, etc

This set of slides makes good reading, with things like "less ductile", "elastic behaviour" and "strength in compression" worth looking for:

[Mechanics of bones by Phillipe GILLET](http://www.montefiore.ulg.ac.be/systems/GBIO/gbio001/chap_2.3.pdf)

A quick search gave many results but of these two shown the first seems **very** interesting from an engineer's perspective:

1. [shock absorbing "goo"](https://www.cam.ac.uk/research/news/shock-absorbing-goo-discovered-in-bone)
2. [shock absorbtion](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3102329/)

Comment: While I think you're right, you can improve your answer by adding literature that supports your thoughts.

Comment: @Arsak As an engineer, I wrote an answer explaining the function in layperson's terms, the OP did not ask for any formulae of how to calculate the maximum stress point or the maximum bending point for a given load. So, for the question asked I think the answer stands as sufficient. If you want to ask a question about stress calculations or whether a cylindrical structure is stronger or weaker than a solid structure you have that option.

Comment: I wasn't thinking about calculations or similar sophisticated level, rather about an introduction to biophysics for example that covers what you've written. And sorry if my comment reads like an attack, that wasn't my intention. I just know that the community prefers well referenced answers to maintain quality of the site.

Comment: While this sounds plausible, it is not correct. Long bones are not curved and they are not springs of any type. Furthermore, your sources do not support your assertions.

Comment: The two sources given are unrelated to the question asked and the answer given. Please provide *appropriate* references related to the specific question and answer asked, not unrelated trivia. I worry that the presence of unrelated citations appears to give an answer more credibility than it deserves - I find this worse than lack of citation and perceive it as a form of academic dishonesty.

Comment: @anongoodnurse please show me a perfectly straight bone.

Comment: Solar Mike, it is not the responsibility of the commenter to prove you wrong; it is the responsibility of the answerer to prove their answer is correct. Users are encouraged to point out wrong answers, not to argue with them.

Comment: As @BryanKrause pointed out, sources should address the question. Your added source, while *long*, does not discuss the axis (straight or curved?) of the bone. Again, it does not support your answer that bones are curved to provide a springlike advantage.

Comment: @anongoodnurse I did not choose it based on the length.... But words like ductile...

Comment: At this point, comments become discussion, so I will not press my point any further, Just looking for an answer based in fact, with proof if needed/challenged.

Comment: @anongoodnurse: After looking at a number of on-line pictures of human skeletons, I have to disagree.  The long bones ARE curved.  Sometimes, as with the femur & tibia, the curvature from end to end can be quite subtle, but it seems to be there. And of course there is a lengthwise curvature, with the ends being wider than the middle.

Comment: @jamesqf - The diaphyses of the long bones are not curved. Tthe anatomical axis (different from the mechanical axis) of the humerus is a straight line. I don't count the joints as curves. Joints are larger/oddly shaped because of their function. The radius/ulna, because of the rotatory function, are slightly  curved. The other long bones (tibia,  humerus, and shorter "long" bones (metacarpals/tarsals, phalanges, etc.) are not. Add all of them together, and the answer is that most bones are not curved. In any case, the answer does not support its assertions. (Bones are curved for springiness.)

Comment: @jamesqf - I don't want to promote an argument from authority, but as an ER doc, I have looked at literally many thousands of xrays over the decades, in addition to, well, studying human anatomy. I can see how someone would think they're curved. But if they are curved, there's something amiss (an old fracture, an early vitamin D deficiency, a musculoskeletal disorder, etc.)

Comment: I don't know anything about biophysics or engineering, but could someone explain why a "rigid" structure is better at absorbing shock if it's curved? If the answer is too long, a link would do.